# spyOn working with Jasmine, but not with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jasmine, jestjs

I'm writing tests for Vue components. Those components import a **const** function like this:

```js
import { overviewModule } from "@/store/overview-module";`
```

And I have methods that access this **const**, for example:

```js
  private sort() {
    const filterOptions = {
      contains: overviewModule.filter.contains,
      desc: !overviewModule.filter.desc
    };

    return overviewModule.updateOverview(filterOptions);
  }
```

When I write my tests, I want to mock the `overviewModule`. I could achieve this with Jasmine `spyOn`, but I could not accomplish the same with `jest.spyOn`.

Here is a simple test case with Jasmine (test is **passing**):

```js
  it("sorts descendent when sort event is called", () => {
    // Arrange
    const overviewModuleSpy = spyOn(overviewModule, "updateOverview");
    overviewModule.filter.contains = "test";
    overviewModule.filter.desc = false;
    const wrapper = shallowMount(TableOverview, {});

    // Act
    wrapper.find(".ic-wissensportal-sort-desc").trigger("click");

    // Assert
    expect(overviewModuleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ contains: "test", desc: true });
  });
```

Here is a the same test case with Jest (test is **not passing**):

```js
  it("sorts descendent when sort event is called", () => {
    // Arrange
    const overviewModuleSpy = jest.spyOn(overviewModule, "updateOverview");
    overviewModule.filter.contains = "test";
    overviewModule.filter.desc = false;
    const wrapper = shallowMount(TableOverview, {});

    // Act
    wrapper.find(".ic-wissensportal-sort-desc").trigger("click");

    // Assert
    expect(overviewModuleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ contains: "test", desc: true });
  });
```

What is the test with `jest.spyOn` not passing?

I assume I'm missing some jest concept?

**EDIT**

Here is the error when using **jest.spyOn**:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The problem was as mentioned in the comments with corss-contamination. The method `updateOverview` was called twice. Once in the **mounted** cycle of the component and the second time in the trigger event of the spec:

First call: const wrapper = shallowMount(TableOverview, {});
Second call: expect(overviewModuleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ contains: "test", desc: true });

Unfortunatelly I still haven't figured out how to clear the state of the spied object so that my `trigger("click")` has a completely new state of the object.

With `jest.clearAllMocks();` after const wrapper = shallowMount(TableOverview, {}); also didn't help.

So, here my tentative:

```
@Component
export default class TableOverview extends Vue {
  private mounted() {
    overviewModule.updateOverview({}); // first
  }

  private sort() {
    const filterOptions = {
      contains: overviewModule.filter.contains,
      desc: !overviewModule.filter.desc
    };

    return overviewModule.updateOverview(filterOptions); // second
  }
}

it("sorts ascendent when sort event is called", () => {
  // Arrange
  const updateOverviewSpy = spyOn(overviewModule, "updateOverview");
  overviewModule.filter.contains = "test";
  overviewModule.filter.desc = true;
  const wrapper = shallowMount(TableOverview, {}); // first call -> calls mounted()
  jest.clearAllMocks(); // doesn't help

  // Act
  wrapper.find(".ic-wissensportal-sort-asc").trigger("click"); // second call

  // Assert
  expect(updateOverviewSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ contains: "test", desc: false });
  expect(updateOverviewSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: What does 'not passing' mean? Please, list the error.

Comment: A spy works correctly and shows what's going on. Since you assigned overviewModule.filter values, it is likely changed somewhere in the comp, and updateOverview is called twice for some reason. No, you're not missing a concept that would be specific to Jest. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Something clearly happens there that wasn't shown, and this 'something' differs in Jasmine and Jest. For starters, you modify overviewModule and likely don't reset it after a test. This may result in test cross-contamination.

Comment: @EstusFlask I understand and I'll analyse that, but it doesn't seem that this object is changed anywhere right now. I'll give a deeper look.

Comment: Since the object belongs to state, it can be modified anywhere the state is involved. Another possible cause is module duplication when `@/store/overview-module` refers to different module copies in different places, but it can be ignored here, it's clearly the same module in app and tests because updateOverview is called. I'd suggest to take care about cross-contamination. You should do jest.resetModules and re-import relevant modules locally with `require` for every test that involves global state, or use jest.isolateModules everywhere global state is used.

Comment: @EstusFlask that was a good point. Also with jasmine, if I use for expectation `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` the test no longer passes, because it says it was called twice. Now I have to find the spot where the cross-contamination is occurring.

Comment: @EstusFlask I updated my question again, so that might help you better for posting an answer if you want.

Comment: It's still unclear why there are 2 calls. Please, provide the entire TableOverview component or a simplified version that can reproduce the problem. If `filter` is modified somewhere in the store, please, provide store code, too. This will likely be enough to know what's going on.

Comment: Providing the code of the store won't help. I found out why it was called twice and it has nothing to do with the store. I'll post the code and you will clearly see where it's called for the first time and for the second.

Comment: Thanks. It remains unclear how `overviewModule.filter.contains` can become undefined in call 2 when it's explicitly set to `test`. This means it's changed somewhere during TableOverview lifespan.